# php ini settings given in .htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, datetime

I need to use time zone PST for my application, so i have set these settings in .htaccess file of my zend project. --

```
    php_value date.timezone "America/Los_Angeles"
```

But it is not being reflected in my project, when i echo the date it is showing me Indian time. What am missing in this please help me to know.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but have you heard about date? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

Ensure `.htaccess` files is of any use. It may be that your httpd is not even reading it (most likely) or it does, but ignores your php_value (less possible as it usually ends with error 500)